# MySQL: index diffrences between innoDB and MyISAM

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, myisam

What are the main differences between index in innoDB and MyISAM?

Comment: That could be helpful:

http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam

Answer (score -2):

InnoDB is a fully [ACID compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) database with support for transactions, [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), replication, and like a modern filesystem keeps a journal of changes so that in case of a sudden crash or hardware malfunction it can recover to the last known-good state of the database.

MyISAM is the original database engine for MySQL with a focus on speed over reliability. It lacks transaction support and doesn't use a journal so if the database crashes it can be easily corrupted. It's a lot like the Linux `ext2` filesystem in this regard. This is a product of the era where a high-end computer might have all of 256MB of memory and a 9GB hard disk was considered large.

While on antiquated hardware MyISAM was a necessity, on modern hardware InnoDB actually performs better. It's been continuously improved since its introduction and has been aggressively optimized. Each point release of MySQL continues to push performance on InnoDB while MyISAM remains largely untouched, left in there purely for legacy concerns.

So unless you have a very good reason you should be using InnoDB for all new applications.